# react-native-charts-wrapper: Not able to get vertical lines every 0.01 increments

Tags: react-native, react-native-charts-wrapper

I have a react expo application and have made a development build so that i can use the 'react-native-charts-wrapper' library. I am trying to use react-native-charts-wrapper": "^0.5.11" to draw out my data point. i am trying to get vertical gridlines every 0.01 seconds but i am not able to do this.  My chart is displayed, but it generates a vertical line every 4 seconds. My goal is to get a 'graph paper' like grid for the LineChart that I currently have. here is my code snippet:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
            <LineChart
                style={{ width: chartWidth2, height: 300 }}
                data={{
                    dataSets: [{
                        label: "ECG",
                        values: dataForChart,
                        config: {
                            drawCircles: false,
                            drawValues: false,
                            color: processColor('red'),
                            lineWidth: 3
                        }
                    }]
                }}
                xAxis={{
                    position: 'BOTTOM',
                    drawGridLines: true,
                    gridColor: processColor('grey'),
                    gridLineWidth: 1,
                    granularity: 0.01,
                    granularityEnabled: true,
                }}
                yAxis={{
                    left: {
                        granularity: 1, 
                        granularityEnabled: true,
                        labelCount: 5, 
                    }
                }}
                touchEnabled={false} // Disabling touch events on the chart itself
                dragEnabled={false}
                scaleXEnabled={false}
                scaleYEnabled={false}
            />
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
```

Can someone help me please?